# Perturbation Expansion

Tags: perturbation-theory

So I have this question in one of my exercises;

> Determine explicitly the first three terms in the expansions of the three roots of $x^3− \epsilon (x^2)−\epsilon^2$.

Notice here the equation doesn't equate to zero. If it did I would go about doing this  by setting

$$x = x(0) + \epsilon x(1) + \cdots$$

and then using the equating coefficients  method for each of the epsilon ($\epsilon$) orders.

Do I have to set this equation equal to zero myself?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly. If you are looking for roots of that cubic, however, then of course you must set the cubic equal to zero.

Comment: I just tried doing this but when I do equate it to zero I am unable to find the three roots since x(0) = 0

Comment: Hmm, I think I understand the problem. Unfortunately I don't know the answer. Hopefully you get one soon!